# Docker How to connect to MongoDB from Web Service inside Container

Tags: java, web, docker

Currently I want to setup a Linux Server with MongoDB and a WebServer which saves stuff inside this DB. I need them both to run inside Docker containers.

My problem is that my WebServer doesnt seem to "see" the MongoDB from inside its container.

What ive tried so far is:
run MongoDB with

docker run -p 27017:27017 -v... repoimage

it initializes fine and I can access this DB through the mongoshell without any problems.
Also the Webserver can access the DB if it DOESNT run in a container but just on the host as java application.

When I try now to run the server through a container I get a java exception saying "Connection refused" (which is thrown when he cant open the socket)

(Important: the server accesses the mongodb through "localhost")

I thought that container networks are "linked" together. Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Give us the java code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localhost will be resolved by the hosts file in the container, hence it won't point outside of the container to the host machines localhost. Run the container with **--net="host"** to resolve.

Also, I would suggest starting up the two containers with docker-compose to have their own network and refer to each other in their host files through their own hashes.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configuring-the-default-network

Comment: this works perfectly, thank you
i will try this link also

Comment: I didnt understood @gerynix, could you please ellaborate this solution, am having the same issue. How to use --net="host" and where to use. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just try to point the Webserver to the correct container IP. You can get the container IP by using this command

`docker inspect <container-uid> | grep IPAddress`.

I believe the default IP for the first container that spins up is 172.17.0.2. This way your Webserver will be pointing to container where MongoDB is running instead of the localhost.